# How do I test whether a property value is changed or not in the test code using xunit in c#

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I have a method which completes the address if the provided address is incomplete and returns the status as either `HighProbabilityMatch` or `MultipleMatch`.

```
if(status=="HighProbabilityMatch")
{
// update the necessary properties of the address object.
}
else if (status=="MultipleMatch")
{
// update only streetName, StreetType, UnitNumber,UnitName etc.
}
```

Now I need to write unit test such that after calling this method, i need to ensure that the required properties are updated accordingly based on the status. 
EG: If the status is MultipleMatch, then I should check that streetName is update while AddressLine1 is not updated.

I have been trying to achieve it with xunit `PropertyChanged` method but it's not working out for me.
Any better suggestions on what to be done will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Please show your test and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't get a direction to begin hence I din't post any. Also it's not direct to post code, it has dependencies.

Comment: `Assert.PropertyChanged(address, nameof(address.Addr1), t=>t.partyConversion.ScrubAddress(address));` is what i tried. `address` is the Address object

Comment: Does your address class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I think in your test you want to set properties of your class and then call your function. Afterwards you compare the property values you set before with the property values after the call.

Comment: @TimRogers Yes it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @DanielSchmid My intent is to test whether the necessary properties are set based on status

Comment: @RaidaAdn Your assertion looks fine. It's one of two problems: either `Address` does not raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` properly, or `ScrubAddress` does not actually change the property. It's impossible to know without seeing your code.

Comment: @TimRogers I think it's better for me to elaborate the scenario fully in another question so that you can better understand and give out better approach